# Is it possible that a surjective map on a non contractible space be null-homotopic?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be a non contractible space and $f:Y\to X$ a surjective map.

> Is it possible that one have $f$ null-homotopic?

If yes,

> Is there some result to help to prove that some specific surjective
> map is **not** null-homotopic?

My searches with keywords did not have any effect, I only got inverse results, like "if $ X $ is a sphere and $ f $ is not surjective, then it is null-homotopic".

Thank you so much.

Comment: Example: any map $S^1\to S^2$ is null-homotopic (this is $\pi_1(S^2)=0$), but there are space-filling curves that surjects an interval (hence also for $S^1$) onto $S^2$.

Comment: If $Y$ is contractible, then any map $f:Y\rightarrow X$ is null homotopic.  As such, one of the easiest example is the covering map $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow S^1$.  In general, knowing a map is surjective is not helpful in showing it's not null homotopic because for many "nice" situations (e.g. compact manifolds), every map is homotopic to a surjective map.

Comment: Thank you both so much

Comment: @JasonDeVito could you post as an answer? Thank you

Comment: @Quiet_waters: Presumably you think about null-homotopic maps like contractibility of their image? yeah?

Comment: @C.F.G yes, I 've got confused with it sometimes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, if $Y$ is contractible, then any map $f:Y\rightarrow X$ is nullhomotopic.  So, in particular, the covering projection $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow S^1$ is an example where $X$ is non-contractible, $f$ is surjective, and $Y$ is contractible.

There are some exceptions, but generally speaking, surjectivity is not well behaved under homotopies:  two maps can be homotopic with one being surjective and the other not being surjective.

Here's a large class of examples.

**Proposition**:  Suppose $M$ and $N$ are connected compact manifolds.  If $M$ has positive dimension, then there is a surjective null homotopic map $f:M\rightarrow N$.

**Proof**:  Choose $p \in M$ and let $U$ be a closed neighborhood of $p$ which is homeomorphic to a closed ball.  Abusing notation, I will identity $U$ with a ball of radius $1$ centered about $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Now, there is a surjective continuous function $f:U\rightarrow [-1/2,1/2]$ which is constantly $0$ on the boundary of the ball.  For example, you can define identify $[-1/2,1/2]$ as a small part of a coordinate axis in $U$, define $f:[-1/2,1/2]\rightarrow [-1/2,1/2]$ as the identity, $f:\partial U\rightarrow [-1/2,1/2]$ as constantly zero, and then use the Tietze extension theorem to define $f$ on all of $U$.

Now, $f$ extends to a surjective continuous map $F:M\rightarrow [-1/2,1/2]$ by defining it to be $0$ outside of $U$.

Armed with $F$, we now use the [Hahn-Mazurkiewicz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve#:%7E:text=The%20Hahn%E2%80%93Mazurkiewicz%20theorem%20is,connected%2C%20second%2Dcountable%20space.) which says that a Hausdorff space $N$ is the continuous image of $[-1/2,1/2]$ if $N$ is compact, connected, locally connected, and second countable.  All of these hypothesis are true for a connected compact manifold $M$ (and even a much larger class of spaces!).  Then the composition $M\rightarrow [-1/2,1/2]\rightarrow N$ is surjective by construction.  Note that the composition factors through a coontractible space, so is null homotopic.  $\square$

However, this is not to say that surjectivity has nothing to do with whether or not a map is null homotopic.  For example,

**Proposition**.  Suppose $M^n$ and $N^n$ are compact oreintable connected $n$-manifolds with no boundary.   Suppose $f:M\rightarrow N$ is continuous and that the induced map $H^n(M;\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H^n(N;\mathbb{Z})$ is non-zero.  Then any map $g$ which is homotopic to $f$ must be surjective.

Proof:  As $H^n(M;\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}$, the induced map is given by multiplication by some integer called the degree of the map.  The degree can be computed by homotoping a map to be smooth, and then doing a signed count of preimages of a regular value.  If $g$ is not surjective, any point which is not in the image of $g$ is a regular value, so $g$ has degree $0$.  Homotopic maps induce the same map on cohomology, so $f$ also has degree $0$. $\square$